# Pandas group by columns and unique count and unique values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by two columns and for other few columns I want to get unique not empty count and comma separated unique values.

sample data

```
[{
"vendor": "ven1",
"event": "event",
"code": "sd",
"gender": "M",
"female": "0"
},
{
"vendor": "ven1",
"event": "event",
"code": "sd",
"gender": "M",
"female": ""
},
{
"vendor": "ven1",
"event": "event",
"code": "sd",
"gender": "M",
"female": "0"
},
{
"vendor": "ven1",
"event": "event2",
"code": "sd",
"gender": "M",
"female": "0"
},
{
"vendor": "ven1",
"event": "event2",
"code": "sd",
"gender": "F",
"female": "0"
}

]
```

I am trying below code, but not getting output as desired

```
result = df.groupby(['vendor', 'event']).agg({
   'code':  ['nunique', 'unique'],
   'gender':  ['nunique', 'unique']
   'cancel': ['nunique', 'unique'],
   'female':  ['nunique', 'unique'],
   'male':  ['nunique', 'unique']

   }).reset_index()
```

I was able to get the count with below

```
result = df.groupby(['vendor', 'event']).agg({
   'code': lambda x: x.nunique(),
   'gender': lambda x: x.nunique(),
   'cancel': lambda x: x.nunique(),
   'female': lambda x: x.nunique(),
   'male': lambda x: x.nunique()

   }).reset_index()
```

But I need to get the unique values, as If unique value is one I need to update the all items of said vendor and event for that column

Any help
Thanks,

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of `df` and the matching expected output

Comment: what does the output look like for this sample data?

Comment: There are no columns **male**  or **cancel** in data supplied. That accepted the code otherwise runs and produces the result which would be expected - how does this differ from your requirement?

Comment: @user19077881, nunique does not ignore case

Comment: @user19077881 and I need that count should ignore empty, but unique value should give the empty value

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{"vendor": "ven1", "event": "event", "code": "sd", "gender": "M", "female": "0"},
{"vendor": "ven1", "event": "event", "code": "sd", "gender": "M", "female": ""},
{"vendor": "ven1", "event": "event", "code": "sd", "gender": "M", "female": "0"},
{"vendor": "ven1", "event": "event2", "code": "sd", "gender": "M", "female": "0"},
{"vendor": "ven1", "event": "event2", "code": "sd", "gender": "F", "female": "0"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def custom_agg(series):
unique_values = series[series.notnull()].unique()
unique_count = len(unique_values)
return unique_count, ', '.join(map(str, unique_values))

result = df.groupby(['vendor', 'event']).agg({
   'code': custom_agg,
   'gender': custom_agg,
   'female': custom_agg,
}).reset_index()

print(result)
```

Result:

```
      Vendor event     code     gender    female
0      ven1     event    (1, sd)     (1, M)  (2, 0, )
1      ven1.    event2   (1, sd)  (2, M, F)    (1, 0)
```

Comment: Code gives the same results as `'code': ['nunique', 'unique']` etc apart from combining the results in a tuple rather than separate columns.

Comment: I need different columns for unique_count and unique_value like code_unique_count, code_unique_value... etc

Comment: @user19077881, nunique does not ignore case

Comment: and I need that count should ignore empty, but unique value should give the empty value